# Getting world position to canvas position for Screen Space - Camera canvas

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a text display over a cube in Unity UI when I freely move my camera. The canvas is set to Screen Space - Camera mode and I set the camera property in the inspector. I have also attached a mouse move script to the camera.

My problem is that the text is barely moving and seems to ignore the position of the cube relative to the camera's viewport. Here is my code:

```
public class UpdateUiMarker : MonoBehaviour {

    public RectTransform element;
    public Transform cube;

    public RectTransform canvas;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void LateUpdate () {
        Vector2 screenPos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(cube.position);
        Vector2 localPos;
        RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(canvas, screenPos, Camera.main, out localPos);
        element.localPosition = localPos;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong (other than `WorldToScreenPoint` is in the Camera class, not the RectTransformUtility class).

Comment: @Draco18s I also tried the Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint method and I get the exact same result.

Comment: What I meant was, I don't see WorldToScreenPoint in the [RectTransformUtilities documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransformUtility.html).

Comment: Yes, you are right. Don't know how I ended up with this particular snippet, I tried a lot of versions I found hoping that I would get a better result

Comment: I corrected the code

Comment: Like I said, except for that anomaly, I don't see anything. :\

Comment: Maybe try World Space Render Mode?

Comment: hi.. is that working now?

Answer (score 5):

First, you may have a `world` Camera look at the `cube` which stuffs as 3D objects, and then other Camera `ui` see your UI elements while culling off 3D objects. Last, a `canvas` Canvas places your UI elements.
Then, you could code like this:

```
var screen = world.WorldToScreenPoint(cube.transform.position);
screen.z = (canvas.transform.position - ui.transform.position).magnitude;
var position = ui.ScreenToWorldPoint(screen);
element.position = position; // element is the Text show in the UI.
```

Comment: I did this with the world and ui cameras being the same one.  Regardless of that, your trick worked like magic...i.e. i'm not sure why this z magnitude fix helped, but thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Working solution for URP (also works on deffered):

```
    public static Vector2 WorldPositionToScreenSpaceCameraPosition(Camera worldCamera, Canvas canvas, Vector3 position)
    {
        Vector2 viewport = worldCamera.WorldToViewportPoint(position);
        Ray canvasRay = canvas.worldCamera.ViewportPointToRay(viewport);
        return canvasRay.GetPoint(canvas.planeDistance);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

uscq answer worked for me. However, I needed to know the world position of a UI Image that was in my canvas. My canvas is using Screen Space - Camera and not Overlay. I modified uscq answer to do the opposite. Thank you so much!

```
    var position = UICamera.WorldToScreenPoint(MyUIObject.transform.position);
    position.z = (thisCanvas.transform.position - UICamera.transform.position).magnitude;
    theLocationOfUIObjectInWorldLocation = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(position);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
void LateUpdate () {
        element.anchoredPosition = Input.mousePosition;
    }
```

And set anchors of element to Vector2.zero for min and max.

Comment: I assume that "element" is on top (that is his direct parent is root Canvas).